# Playing mp3 files with mciSendString (MCIERR_CANNOT_LOAD_DRIVER)

Tags: c++, audio, mp3, mcisendstring

I am trying to write some code that can play an .mp3 file. I thought I could use the mciSendString call, but I am getting a strange error.

So, when I have this code:

```
int rc=mciSendString(L"open songname.mp3 alias song1", NULL, 0, 0);
```

`rc` returns with the number 266, and the error string returned with `GetErrorString` was:

> "Unknown problem while loading the specified device driver."
>
> Error 266 is MCIERR_CANNOT_LOAD_DRIVER

I have also tried:

```
int rc=mciSendString(L"open songname.mp3 type mpegvideo alias song1", NULL, 0, 0);
```

and received the same error.

I thought it may be the mp3 file, but I tried a few different ones and kept getting the same error.

My code is in C++ and is running on Windows 7. Is my code missing something?

Comment: Well, do you have a MP3 codec installed that MCI can use?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I assumed that Windows comes with it preinstalled. Windows Media Player can play the mp3 files I am attempting to play. Is that a valid way to check, or is there something else I should do to check if it is installed.

Comment: Windows Media File does not use MCI for playback IIRC. _Assuming_ anything -- particularly about something that is not working -- seems an odd choice.

Comment: Try giving a full, absolute path.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I tried the full and absolute path, and that didn't seem to help. But, I tested the same call with a wav file, and it worked. It seems that you are are correct about the mp3 codec not being installed. Thanks. Do you know of a mci mp3 codec that I can install?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember the solution, though I hope it makes you feel a little better when I say I vaguely recall having struggled with exactly the same thing in the past.

Comment: As an aside, consider using an actual media library like [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/). MCI is designed for little sound effects.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding `songname.mp3` with an extra pair of quotes (be sure to escape them with backslashes).

Comment: Good thought, but when I changed the call with the quotes, I still got the same 266 error. Sadly didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I didn't have an mp3 codec for MCI. (Actually answered by @LightnessRacesinOrbit in comments to the question.)